# URL rewrite - check for https and add www

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting

I've tried several answers on stackoverflow and non are working for me. I basically need all traffic on my site to end up at https://www.domainname.com. I can get everything working with the rules below except if someone types in https://domainname.com. In this case I need to add www to it.

````
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="^domainname.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainname.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domainname.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add www to the url in iis, you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="RedirectNonWwwToWww" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domainname.com$" />
     </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainname.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working.  Everything works except when I type in "https : //domainname.com" into my browser - it does not add the "www" for some reason to yield "https : //www.domainname.com".  Since I have a wildcard SSL certificate, I need it to resolve to the www version.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your first rule:

<add input="{HTTP}" pattern="^domainname.com$"

FIRST: I'm not sure that input="{HTTP}" is correct and/or exist. IF exist I think that look only at HTTP not HTTPS... So when you type in "https : //domainname.com" there's no rule matching...

I think you have to use this configuration:

```
<rule name="NonWWWtoWWW">
    <match url="(.*)" /> 
    <conditions> 
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domainname\.com$" negate="true" /> 
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainname.com/{R:1}" /> 
</rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domainname.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```